# Dynamic thumbprint update

Tags: ssl, wif, adfs

In my company certificates expire often. Every time on the expiration of a certificate, we need to update thumbprint for it in our config files manually and do it in different environments. 
Is there a way to update thumbprints dynamically when certificates are replaced? Is it possible to establish a relying trust between ADFS and relying party?

Currently, we are using ADFS 2.0. We are soon switching to ADFS 3.0. Was this problem addressed in ADFS 3.0?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WS-Federation middleware for Katana has a dynamic update feature. This is the replacement for the old FAM/SAM plumbing of WIF and does exactly what you are asking for:

http://leastprivilege.com/2014/02/21/test-driving-the-ws-federation-authentication-middleware-for-katana/